# R - Drawing a random sample with fixed probabilities

Tags: r, replace, sample

I'm trying to write a loop in R to create 200 data frames based on random sampling of the original data set. I would like the sample to be drawn with replacement with a fixed proportion of 10% Male (coded as 1) and 90% Female (coded as 0) - variable SEX - and the same number of rows as the original data set.

Here is how far I got:

```
for (i in 1:200) {

 smpl[i] <- data[sample(nrow(data), nrow(data), replace=T, prob=ifelse(data$SEX==1,0.1,0.9)),] 

}
```

That code unfortunately doesn't work...

Firstly the code for drawing a random sample does not keep the proportions of male to female to 0.1:0.9.

Secondly when I try to loop over the command I get an error message:

Warning in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(ID = c(32604L, 11645L,  :
  provided 41 variables to replace 1 variables

Could anyone help?

Comment: What's `cox` and why isn't `nrow(data)`? What's `smpl`? Is it a correctly allocated list? Why you don't use `smpl[[i]]`? Don't say just "it doesn't work", but specify the issue you are having (an error? unexpected result? a warning?)

Comment: Hi! Sorry, added missing info to the original post. The code draws a random sample but not within the specified proportions. When I try to loop 200 times over it to create 200 data frames it doesn't execute it... (the name of my original data set was "cox"-copy paste mistake)

Comment: You should allocate a `list` before the loop: `smpl<-vector("list",200)` and inside the loop use `smpl[[i]]<-` with the double square bracket. What you mean with "does not keep the proportions"? It's normal that the obtained sample is not exactly 180-20 due to variance of sampling.

Comment: The code draws a random sample but the proportion of male to female is nowhere near 20-180 but rather 4-196 (it changes at each sample draw but never near 10%:90%).

Comment: Thanks for the tip to create a list before looping - it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some sample data:

```
## Sample data
nMen <- 50
nWomen <- 60

set.seed(124)

mydata <- data.frame(SEX = rep(c("female", "male"), times = c(nWomen, nMen)),
    myValue = rnorm(nMen + nWomen), ID = seq_len(nMen + nWomen))
```

Then, calculate the number of women and men you'd like in each sample - These must be integers

```
## Number of women and men for the sampling
nSampW <- (nWomen + nMen) * 0.9
nSampM <- (nWomen + nMen) * 0.1
## These should be integer (the following should be TRUE)
nSampW %% 1 ==0
nSampM %% 1 ==0
```

Then set up your results vector - the following creates a list with space for 200 samples

```
## Set up results list
mySamp <- vector(mode = "list", length = 200)
```

Then loop, sampling the number of men and women calculated above from the indexes divided by sex

```
## The loop
for(i in seq_along(mySamp)) {
## Get indices by SEX
    idxW <- which(mydata$SEX == "female")
    idxM <- which(mydata$SEX == "male")
## Sample corresponding number of rows from those indexes with replacement
    tempW <- mydata[sample(idxW, nSampW, replace = TRUE), ]
    tempM <- mydata[sample(idxM, nSampM, replace = TRUE), ]
## rbind back together and assign
    mySamp[[i]] <- rbind(tempW, tempM)
}
```

Then check to see whether the proportions are correct

```
# sapply(mySamp[1:10], function(x) prop.table(table(x$SEX)))
#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# female  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9   0.9
# male    0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1   0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

your code would never give you an exact 10%-90% split.

how about this:

```
ans <- list()
# sample data
data_test <- data.frame(SEX = sample(c(0,1 ), 100, replace = TRUE), val = rnorm(100))

for(i in 1 : 200){

    data_m <- data_test[data_test$SEX == 1, ]
    data_m1 <- data_m[sample(nrow(data_m), floor(nrow(data_test) * 0.1), replace = TRUE), ]

    data_f <- data_test[data_test$SEX == 0, ]
    data_f1 <- data_f[sample(nrow(data_f), floor(nrow(data_test) * 0.9), replace = TRUE), ]

    new_data <- rbind(data_f1, data_m1)
    ans[[i]] <- new_data
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's awesome! I thought about something similar also but was hoping to make sure of "prob" argument in function "sample" (naively was hoping the code could be easier).